# php login to mysql encrypted password

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to setup a php login form into a existing database that i do not want to modify, it seems I've made all the right connections to the DB and the right tables, but the password is encrypted and when i try to login it says **"Wrong password. Try again**

this is my code

```
/**
 * log in with post data
 */
private function dologinWithPostData()
{
    // check login form contents
    if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Username field was empty.";
    } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Password field was empty.";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) {

        // create a database connection, using the constants from config/db.php (which we loaded in index.php)
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        // change character set to utf8 and check it
        if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
        }

        // if no connection errors (= working database connection)
        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

            // escape the POST stuff
            $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

            // database query, getting all the info of the selected user (allows login via email address in the
            // username field)
            $sql = "SELECT nickname, user_email, user_password
                    FROM tbl_users
                    WHERE nickname = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_name . "';";
            $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

            // if this user exists
            if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {

                // get result row (as an object)
                $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();

                // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided password fits
                // the hash of that user's password
                if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row->user_password_hash)) {

                    // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your server)
                    $_SESSION['nickname'] = $result_row->user_name;
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                    $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;

                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Wrong password. Try again.";
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "This user does not exist.";
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = "Database connection problem.";
        }
    }
}
```

how can i make this login to the DB since the passwords stored in the DB are encrypted?

Comment: Do you know how the passwords are hashed?

Comment: As DreadfulWeather has suggested: Learn about PDO. And always use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are probably hashed first you must determine which [hashing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) used at storing passwords at your database. Then you can do it like below i assumed passwords are hashed using md5 which is widely used but exploitable but if password is also [salted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) im afraid you have to learn salt word too else it is next to impossible based on used hashing algorithm. Also using this way to access to database is really vulnerable i really suggest for you to look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/tr/book.pdo.php).

```
$sql = "SELECT nickname, user_email, user_password
                FROM tbl_users
                WHERE nickname = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_name . "'AND user_password = ''" . md5($user_password)."'";
```